# Laravel Horizon: A job is always paused

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-horizon

On the Laravel Horizon dashboard, some job always shows as "paused":

[image]

How can I prevent this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It seemed to work and suddenly jobs would pause for no reason. I was using two applications with the same redis server, so conflicts would occur occasionally.

To resolve this you need to modify `config/database.php` and change the value of the key `redis.default.database` so the two (or more) applications don't mix up their keys.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I have default.database => 0, and queue.database => 2. The problem still occurs